# newscoop installation error

Tags: php, zend-framework, newscoop

When trying to install the Newscoop 4 Script ob my website...I get this Error:

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/content/24/8222924/html/newscoop4/application.php on line 65

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/content/24/8222924/html/newscoop4/application.php on line 68
```

and the file it shows error in is this, i think it has something to do with the back slashes because php cant render it completely but my php version is 5.3 hopefully:

```
    <?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', __DIR__ . '/application');

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// goes to install process if configuration files does not exist yet
if (!defined('INSTALL') && (!file_exists(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../conf/configuration.php')
    || !file_exists(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../conf/database_conf.php'))) {
    $subdir = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/', -2));

    if (strpos($subdir, 'install') === false) { 
        header("Location: $subdir/install/");
        exit;
    }
}

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../include'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

if (!function_exists('stream_resolve_include_paths')) {
    function stream_resolve_include_paths($filename) {
        foreach (explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path()) as $include_path) {
            $realpath = realpath("{$include_path}/{$filename}");
            if ($realpath !== false) {
                return $realpath;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

if (!stream_resolve_include_paths('Zend/Application.php')) {
    // include libzend if we don't have zend_application
    set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
        '/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php',
        get_include_path(),
    )));
}

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

if (defined('INSTALL')) {
    $oldErrorReporting = error_reporting();
    error_reporting(0);

    if (!class_exists('Zend_Application', FALSE)) {
        die('Missing dependency! Please install Zend Framework library!');
    }

    error_reporting($oldErrorReporting);
}

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new \Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV);

// Set config
$setConfig = function(Zend_Application $application) {
    require_once 'Zend/Config/Ini.php';
    $defaultConfig = new \Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini-dist', APPLICATION_ENV);
    $config = $defaultConfig->toArray();
    if (is_readable(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini')) {
        try {
            $userConfig = new \Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
            $config = $application->mergeOptions($config, $userConfig->toArray());
        } catch (\Zend_Config_Exception $e) { // ignore missing section
        }
    }
    $application->setOptions($config);
};

$setConfig($application);
unset($setConfig);

>
```

Comment: If you upload a file `version.php` which contains `<?php echo PHP_VERSION;` - what does it say? If it is < PHP 5.3 then yes, it is because there is no PHP 5.3 installed.